# SCSS files not importing in create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm using the React cli `create-react-app` and trying to load in a .scss file from a UI library http://react-conventions.herokuapp.com/. I've already run `npm run eject` and added the following to `loaders` in the `config.dev` I also downloaded the sass-loader already.

```
var path = require('path');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var findCacheDir = require('find-cache-dir');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
var InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
var WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-   utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
var getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
var paths = require('./paths');

var publicPath = '/';

var env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

module.exports = {

  entry: [

    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),

    require.resolve('./polyfills'),

    paths.appIndexJs

  ],
  output: {

    path: paths.appBuild,

    pathinfo: true,

    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',

    publicPath: publicPath
  },
  resolve: {

    fallback: paths.nodePaths,

    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx', ''],
    alias: {

      'react-native': 'react-native-web'
    }
  },

  module: {
    // First, run the linter.
    // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: 'eslint',
        include: paths.appSrc,
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      // Process JS with Babel.
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: paths.appSrc,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {

          // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
          // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/react-scripts/
          // directory for faster rebuilds. We use findCacheDir() because of:
          // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/483
          cacheDirectory: findCacheDir({
            name: 'react-scripts'
          })
        }
      },
      // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
      // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
      // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
      // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
      // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style!css?importLoaders=1!postcss'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"],
        exclude: /node_modules(?!\/react-conventions)/
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
      },
      // JSON is not enabled by default in Webpack but both Node and Browserify
      // allow it implicitly so we also enable it.
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      },
      // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
      // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
      // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'file',
        query: {
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
        }
      },
      // "url" loader works just like "file" loader but it also embeds
      // assets smaller than specified size as data URLs to avoid requests.
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  // We use PostCSS for autoprefixing only.
  postcss: function() {
    return [
      autoprefixer({
        browsers: [
          '>1%',
          'last 4 versions',
          'Firefox ESR',
          'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
        ]
      }),
    ];
  },
  plugins: [

    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin({
      PUBLIC_URL: publicUrl
    }),
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
    }),

    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env),
    // This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only):
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),

    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules)
  ],

  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty'
  }
};
```

I try to import in my component using `import Input from 'react-conventions/lib/Input';` But I'm still getting an error

Failed to compile.

Error in ./~/react-conventions/lib/components/Input/style.scss
Module parse failed: /Users/user/Desktop/App/node_modules/react- conventions/lib/components/Input/style.scss Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
 @ ./~/react-conventions/lib/components/Input/Input.js 19:13-36

Could this be a problem with the library? Doubtful but I'm just not seeing what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

try this (exclude with a negative lookahead):

```
 {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"],
    exclude: /node_modules(?!\/react-conventions)/
 }
```

Comment: could you post more code of your `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: do you have github link?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your package.json scripts

```
"scripts": {
"build-css": "node-sass src/ -o src/",
"watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive"
```

and install also node-sass since the scripts depend on it. 
This will work assuming you haven't eject your project yet.